# Null Pointer Exception When Attempting to create a pop up window in a listView with custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, popup, popupwindow

Im attempting to make a pop up window after I click a button in a listView, and then close it by clicking outside of the box. However, I am getting this error when I attempt to click the button.

```
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.IBinder android.view.View.getWindowToken()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:897)
                                                                                     at logistica.enviaflores.com.logistica.utilities.MyAdapter$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:81)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I can't exactly understand what I am doing wrong for it to throw a null pointer exception. Perhaps i'm coding it incorrectly, but it seems right to me even after I go back and look at it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Bean> mList;
    private PopupWindow popUpWindow;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Bean> list){
    mContext=context;
    mList=list;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    //use convertView recycle
    if(convertView==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.content_orders, parent, false);
        holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        holder.information= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //set text and url
    holder.information.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.information_popup, null);
            popUpWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 400,400,true);
//***I believe the problem happens right in the line under this sentence!***
            popUpWindow.showAtLocation(v.findViewById(R.id.orders), Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);

            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    popUpWindow.dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).resize(500,500).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button information;
    Button close;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full logcat, maybe we can deduce something useful from it. Also pay attention to the line numbers in it, and try to highlight for us the line of your code where the error occurs.

Comment: @Vucko I have now posted the logcat. The error occurs in the onclick listener within the adapter. I assumed it would be a bit obvious but thanks for pointing it out for those who wouldn't understand. :)

Comment: Make sure that a view with id **R.id.orders** exists in **v**

Comment: @TodorKostov what do you mean exactly by that? I have a relative layout in my content_orders.xml file and I named it "orders". Then i tried showAtLocation(v.findViewById(R.id.orders).  I thought that's all i needed, but if not then how can i make sure that R.id.orders exists in V?

Comment: Well **v** is the view that WAS clicked. In your case the **information** button. And searching for **R.id.orders** in it will definitely result in a **NullPointerException**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of searching for **R.id.orders** in the **information** button view, search for in the **convertView**

**Old code:**

```
popUpWindow.showAtLocation(v.findViewById(R.id.orders), Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
```

**New code:**

```
popUpWindow.showAtLocation(convertView.findViewById(R.id.orders), Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
```